How can I setup a bridge from Wifi to a local Ethernet using a Raspberry Pi and a basic Ethernet switch?
I would like to setup an Ethernet switch in the garage which will provide connections to the same LAN segment as the main building. However, there is no network cable between the main building and the garage, but there is WiFi coverage in the garage.
I have already accomplished what I want with a TP-Link Archer A7 router which supports wireless bridge mode. However I would really like to do it with a simple Raspberry Pi and a basic ethernet switch instead.
By using GRE TAP interfaces/tunnel, I was almost able to succeed, but it struggles with long packets (because of some annoying MTU issue), so many packets are lost. I have also found some ways online to solve this using NAT, but this is not acceptable in my use-case. The devices connecting to the switch need to be on the same LAN segment as all other devices in the main building.
Can somebody provide an answer of the best way to accomplish this?

You're using the words "LAN segment" and "bridge". Are you really meaning that, in the Ethernet (IEEE 802.3D) way? Or would a routed network be good enough (note: routing is not the same as NAT)?

Yes, I mean that devices connected to the switch in the garage should appear just like any other device connected in the main building. They should get IP address from the same DHCP server without having to reconfigure the DHCP server and be in the same LAN IP range (192.168.1.0/24)

Note that this indeed opens up a can of worms because large ethernet frames might need to get split up and reassembled. But yes, that works, I've done it in the past with OpenWRT; needs a magic daemon that handles these things, let me look up the name. Note that it's really not a good idea, still, and having separate ethernet segments is what you should do when you have a non-ethernet link in between. IP ranges are completely orthogonal to this, as long as DHCP and ARP get forwarded.

I see some people differentiates between Ethernet segment and LAN segment. The first being the physical transport medium, while the second means anyone being able to reach each other using OSI layer 2. I mean the second.

I fail to understand the general statement "it's really not a good idea". There are many cases where this might be useful - especially for home networks where you just want to throw up another switch somewhere else in the house for devices without wifi and there is no easy way to stretch cables. And all other devices on the network will just see them as any other device - no extra configuration needed. There will be some more broadcast packets on the wifi bridge - but that's it.

If OpenVPN was your solution, great, but that doesn't mean you have to tag the question with it, as that isn't about OpenVPN in particular

I was able to get this to work now using OpenVPN TAP connections. OpenVPN does not seem to suffer from the same MTU issue as GRE TAP because it automatically fragments long ethernet frames into multiple UDP packets.
The following approach depends on one Raspberry Pi in the main building also (or some kind of linux machine that can run OpenVPN..).
Raspberry Pi number 1 (main building)
On the Raspberry Pi in the main building (physically connected to the main ethernet side), I modified /etc/network/interfaces to say:
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet manual

auto br0 
iface br0 inet static
    address 192.168.1.49   # <-- my static IP of choice
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 192.168.1.1
    bridge-ports eth0

This makes sure that there is a bridge available to connect the TAP interface to.
On RPi 1, I also created the following OpenVPN configuration file.
dev tap0
port 9123
proto udp   
keepalive 10 120
script-security 2
up /etc/openvpn/up_tap0.sh

(I am showing without encryption configured to save space. It is also not a big issue in my case since it only runs on the local network. No encryption also helps for speed).
The up_tap0.sh script which runs when openvpn starts simply attaches the tap0 interface to the bridge:
#!/bin/sh
brctl addif br0 tap0
ip link set dev tap0 up

Raspberry Pi number 2 (garage)
On the second raspberry Pi (in the garage), I first made sure it has a connection to the Wifi network (using NetworkManager or /etc/network/interfaces). Then I created this OpenVPN configuration:
remote 192.168.1.49  # <- pointing to server
port 9123
dev tap0
proto udp
keepalive 10 120
persist-tun
script-security 2
up /etc/openvpn/up_tap0.sh

The script up_tap0.sh on RPi2, contains the following:
#!/bin/bash
brctl addbr br0
brctl addif br0 tap0
brctl addif br0 eth0
ip link set dev tap0 up
ip link set dev eth0 up
ip link set dev br0 up

After starting OpenVPN on both RPi1 and RPi2, and connecting a switch and a computer to the available Ethernet port of RPi2 in the garage, I was able to get an IP address via DHCP! :) And it seems to work quite well. The other computer now appears as any other device on this network.

On openwrt, there's a solution to extend networks via a wifi "bridge".
It relies on the openwrt-relayd (attention, there's other "relayd" software out there, so confusion all around).
If your access point and your RPi's wifi hardware support it, WiFi mesh according to 802.11s is much preferrable, however. Check using iw list, looking for mesh point after "Supported interface modes".
